# A bijection between the set of all sequences whose terms are either 0 or 1, and the set of all sequences whose terms are 0, 1 or - 1.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let X be the set of all sequences whose terms are either 0 or 1. Let Y be the set of all sequences whose terms are 0, 1 or    - 1.
We know that both are uncountable sets, by Cantor's diagonal technique.
 Give a bijection between X and Y explicitly. As X and Y are uncountable, there exists bijections to R, the set of real numbers, a composition of these, will give a bijection between X and Y. But, how to get an explicit bijection between X and Y?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the set of $\{0,1\}$-sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ and $Y$ be the set of $\{0,1,2\}$-sequences $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots)$. Denote by $X_0$ and $Y_0$ the subsets of sequences with only finitely many terms $\ne0$, and by $X_\infty$ and $Y_\infty$ the subsets of sequences with infinitely many terms $\ne0$. Furthermore we need the auxiliary set
$$Z:=\>]0,1]\>\sqcup\>{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$$ ($\>\sqcup\>$ denotes the disjoint union). We now produce explicit bijective maps $$f:\>X\to Z,\qquad g:\>Y\to Z\ ,$$
so that $\psi:=g^{-1}\circ f$ maps $X$ bijectively onto $Y$. Namely:
$$f(x):=\left\{\eqalign{\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k 2^{-k}\qquad&(x\in X_\infty) \cr \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k2^{k-1}\quad&(x\in X_0)\cr}\right.\quad,\qquad 
g(y):=\left\{\eqalign{\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k 3^{-k}\quad&(y\in Y_\infty) \cr \sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k3^{k-1}\quad&(y\in Y_0)\cr}\right.\quad.$$
It is well known that $\tilde f:\>x\mapsto\sum_{k=1}x_k2^{-k}$ maps $X$ almost bijectively onto the real interval $[0,1]$, the exemption being that the two sequences $(x_1,\ldots, x_r,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$ and $(x_1,\ldots, x_r,0,1,1,1,\ldots)$ are mapped on the same number $\xi\in[0,1]$. The partition $X=X_0\cup X_\infty$ collects all zero-ending sequences in $X_0$, and $\tilde f$ maps $X_\infty$ bijectively onto $\>]0,1]$. The sequences in $X_0$ are then used to produce finite natural numbers $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$ via binary representation. – Similarly for $g$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to get a more explicit bijection?